# C++ cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**'

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void arrSelectSort(int *[], int), showArrPtr(int *, int);
void showArray(int [] , int);

int main()
{
    int numDonations;
    int *arrPtr;
    cout << "What was the number of donations?: ";
    cin >> numDonations;
    arrPtr = new int[numDonations];
    cout << "What were the donations values?: ";
    for (int count = 0; count < numDonations; count++)
        cin >> arrPtr[count];
    arrSelectSort(arrPtr, 3);
    cout << "The donations, sorted in ascending order are: \n";
    showArrPtr(arrPtr, 3);
    cout << "The donations, in their orginal order are: \n";
    showArray(values, 3);
    system(" Pause ");
    return 0;
}

void arrSelectSort(int *array[], int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex;
    int* minElem;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minElem = array[startScan];
        for(int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (*(array[index]) < *minElem)
            {
                minElem = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = minElem;
    }
}

void showArray(int array[], int size)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        cout << array[count] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void showArrPtr(int *array, int size)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        cout << *(array[count]) << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

This is very confusing and I cannot figure out how to pass a dynamically memory allocation array to a function. I know it's possible because this is part of the exercise in the C++ packet. When I try to remove the bracket in the selectsort function, it gives me some errors inside. when I try to remove the * it gives me other errors.

Comment: Just use `std::vector<int>` and stop worrying about this kind of problem.

Comment: Can you point out which line your compile error is actually coming from?

Comment: Just pass as in showArray function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void arrSelectSort(int *[], int)
```

The first parameter is of type `int**`.

You call the function like this:

```
arrSelectSort(arrPtr, 3);
```

where `arrPtr` is of type `int*`. This is the type mismatch that the compiler is informing your of.

I think that the error is in the declaration of `arrSelectSort`. It should be:

```
void arrSelectSort(int[], int)
```

The first parameter is now of type `int*`. This is exactly you need, a pointer to an array of `int`.

You then have a load of other errors in the implementation of `arrSelectSort` but I don't particularly want to attempt to debug them all.

You'll need to make `minElem` be of type `int`. And in a couple of other places you'll need to remove a level of indirection. For instance, this line:

```
if (*(array[index]) < *minElem)
```

should be:

```
if (array[index] < minElem)
```

and so on.

Comment: and then he will probably have an error on this line `*(array[index])`

Comment: Thanks, had to modify this from another program to make it hold any amount of integers, but was really confusing